# Homogeneous system and periodic solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

im trying to understand periodicity of solutions and I got this problem that I could not solve no matter how much time I spent looking t it. I dont even know where to start:

**Problem**

Lets consider $\dot x = A(t)x$ where

$A(t) = \left [ \begin{matrix}
    a(t) & b(t) \\
    c(t) & d(t) \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

and $a,b,c,d$ are continuous functions with period $1$. Suppose that $a(t)>0,d(t)>0$. Show that for all integers $k>2$, the system **cannot have a periodic solution $x(t)$ with minimal period equal to $k$.**

Thanks so much for all your answers. <3